# Is there a Dharmic requirement that a religious speaker must believe in what he/she is preaching?

Tags: dharma, sects

Hinduism is broken up into sects and sects disagree, sometimes strongly, about religious matters.  The following is said to have happened in real life.  A speaker, belonging to sect A was a very good speaker.  He also knew the Puranas and other narrative material of sect B that he did not believe in.  Because he was such a good speaker, laypersons of sect B invited him to speak to them and expound on their sect.

He wrote to a leader of his sect about this, and this leader advised him to take the fees and give the discourse.

Was he being Dharmic to his sect or to the sect that was paying him?

Comment: The answer to this riddle, may depend on what was said. I can speak truly with Christians, even though I sometimes need to use their terms instead of ours—in order for them to comprehend. Regardless, this question invites opinion and risks being closed without a rewrite.

Comment: Kumarila Bhatta killed himself horribly through Kushagni Pravesha because he betrayed Buddhists by joining their moanstery not as a sincere student but only to learn their doctrines to refute them. @RubelliteYakṣī .  But i have learnt that once you trigger the powers that be at HSE then nothing can save your question.

Comment: With enough work at figuring out how to avoid triggering them with specific words  & phrasing it can be done, but it's not worth the effort. Don't worry, by next year there will probably be an AI with access to all the texts & records, then we can ask and receive more neutral answers that can then be fact, checked. Not just HSE, but nearly all of SE will be replaced by LLMs. Quora has already embraced it with Poe.

Comment: My main concern is the LLMs that are trained on sites like this when they are full of contradictory biases.